# 47deg Android Swipe Listview on Eclipse

Tags: java, android

I am using eclipse with adt to developing android apps
I want to use 47deg Android Swipe Listview library in my app

Is this library created just for Android Studio IDE And is there any way to use this in eclipse?
(Because it has some files in it like build.gradle and ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my own experience, there is no easy way to do that. the project meta-data is significantly different so eclipse and Android Studio are not compatible in that respect.

I created a new project in Eclipse and added the source files manually. alternatively - I found instructions on how to open an older version of the project in eclipse here- https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/wiki (which I intend to try tomorrow).

Good luck!